# Calculated column not provision to List

Tags: spfx, spfx-webparts

I have tried to provision a Calculated column to SharePoint using the SPFx but it seems the column is not added to List.

It's provision successfully to the Site Columns as well as the Content Type but not to the List.

Below are my elements.xml and schema.xml for the List:

Elements.xml:

```
<Field ID="{267ea2b3-5481-4488-81d0-22866c0008e6}"
    Name="ValidDate"
    DisplayName="Valid To Date"
    Type="Calculated"
    Format="DateOnly"
    ResultType="DateTime"
    ReadOnly="TRUE"
    Group="Custom Survey Columns">
        <Formula>=[Created] + [ExpirationDays]</Formula>
        <FieldRefs>
            <FieldRef Name="Created"/>
            <FieldRef Name="ExpirationDays"/>
        </FieldRefs>
</Field>
<Field ID="{4e03d102-ae74-4750-b125-deaa06db981c}"
    Name="ExpirationDays"
    DisplayName="Expiration Days"
    Type="Number"
    Group="Custom Survey Columns">
</Field>

<ContentType ID="0x0100d21b478842d443fa999a79756cc76ae7" 
    Name="SurveyUrlContentType" 
    Group="Survey Url Content Types"
    Description="Survey Content Type">
    <FieldRefs>
        <FieldRef ID="{267ea2b3-5481-4488-81d0-22866c0008e6}" />      
        <FieldRef ID="{4e03d102-ae74-4750-b125-deaa06db981c}" />                      
    </FieldRefs>
</ContentType>

<ListInstance
    CustomSchema="schema.xml"
    FeatureId="00bfea71-de22-43b2-a848-c05709900100"
    Title="Survey Url" 
    Description="Survey Url List"
    TemplateType="100"
    Hidden="FALSE"
    OnQuickLaunch="FALSE"
    Url="Lists/SurveyUrl">
</ListInstance>
```

Schema.xml:

```
<List xmlns:ows="Microsoft SharePoint" Title="Survey Url" DisableAttachments="TRUE" EnableContentTypes="TRUE" FolderCreation="FALSE" Direction="$Resources:Direction;" VersioningEnabled="FALSE" Url="Lists/SurveyUrl" BaseType="0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/">
  <MetaData>
    <ContentTypes>
      <ContentTypeRef ID="0x0100d21b478842d443fa999a79756cc76ae7" />
    </ContentTypes>
    <Fields>
      <Field Name="LinkTitle" DisplayName="Name" Type="Text"  />
      <Field Name="Title" DisplayName="Name" Type="Text" Indexed="TRUE" />
    </Fields>
    <Views>
      <View BaseViewID="1" Type="HTML" WebPartZoneID="Main" DisplayName="$Resources:core,objectiv_schema_mwsidcamlidC24;" DefaultView="TRUE" MobileView="TRUE" MobileDefaultView="TRUE" SetupPath="pages\viewpage.aspx" ImageUrl="/_layouts/images/generic.png" Url="AllItems.aspx">
        <XslLink Default="TRUE">main.xsl</XslLink>
        <JSLink>clienttemplates.js</JSLink>
        <RowLimit Paged="TRUE">30</RowLimit>
        <Toolbar Type="Standard" />
        <ViewFields>
          <FieldRef Name="ID"></FieldRef>
          <FieldRef Name="LinkTitle"></FieldRef>
          <FieldRef Name="ExpirationDays" />
          <FieldRef Name="ValidDate" />
        </ViewFields>
        <Query>
          <OrderBy>
            <FieldRef Name="ID" />
          </OrderBy>
        </Query>
      </View>
    </Views>
    <Forms>
      <Form Type="DisplayForm" Url="DispForm.aspx" SetupPath="pages\form.aspx" WebPartZoneID="Main" />
      <Form Type="EditForm" Url="EditForm.aspx" SetupPath="pages\form.aspx" WebPartZoneID="Main" />
      <Form Type="NewForm" Url="NewForm.aspx" SetupPath="pages\form.aspx" WebPartZoneID="Main" />
    </Forms>
  </MetaData>
</List>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should add a reference to the created out of the box field in your content type définition